# Working with "circular stacked" elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have  CSS dropdown menus, jquery dialogs, and other jquery components on my webpage.

The problem I'm having is that the dropdown menus need to be above the other jquery components but below the dialogs, and the components need to be above the dialogs but below the dropdown and the dialogs need to be above the dropdowns but below the components.

Visual Aid:

[image]

So this problem isn't as easy as just setting a `z-index`.

I've tried quickly hiding/showing the menu when a dialog is opened (effectively hiding the menu as it relies on the hover to stay active to stay open).

Code:

```
$('.allegDropdownMenu').css("display", "none");
$('.allegDropdownMenu').css("display", "");
```

The problem is that this code seem to execute so quickly that he hover state never become inactive.

I've added a timeout of 10ms but it seems like a really messy and hacky way of doing it.

So I guess I'm wondering if anyone has any solutions for this type of problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean by "Singleton Components". Can you elaborate?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn -- I changed the wording. They are just other jquery components on the page. The word singleton only served to emphasize that I'm using the same component everywhere meaning I can't just tell the component to display differently in different spots without some heavy modification.

Comment: Why are you changing the display state to `none` and then `""`, what was that supposed to accomplish? it's synchronous so doing one immediately after the other doesn't really make much sense. Does your dropdown have a close method that would allow you to force it to close on demand?

Comment: The dropdown is just CSS that relies on hover states to stay open. The dialogs use AJAX to load, and I could put closing logic into the AJAX successes but that seems overly difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

could pseudo element in blue box covering green box do the trick ?

```
div {
  height:2em;
  line-height:2em;
  width:8.5em;
  background:gray;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  text-shadow:0 0 2px white;
}
#blue  {background:#505DDA;z-index:3;}
#red   {background:#DA5050;z-index:2;}
#green {background:#50DA74;}
#blue:after {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  height:2.6em;
  width:2em;
  right:2px;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  background:#50DA74;
  transform:rotate(-27deg) ;
}

#blue {
  transform:rotateZ(90deg) ;
  transform-origin:7% 80% ;
}
#red {
  transform:rotateZ(27deg);
  transform-origin: 40%;
}
#green {
  transform:rotateZ(-27deg) ;
  transform-origin:right 110%;
}
```

```
<div id="blue"> BLUE </div>
<div id="red"> RED </div>
<div id="green"> GREEN</div>
```

demo http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vKCeF

Comment: Certainly very interesting. Though my visual example was merely to show how the elements on the page are layered, they are not in it of themselves the actual elements, nor what they actually look like. But this is pretty cool!

Comment: okay, i totally misunderstood the whole thing. thanks for you feed back :)